# How do you convert a CSV file into a 2d array in a .js file?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, csv

I have this csv file that looks a bit like this:

```
1,2,3
3,4,5
5,6,7
```

and I need to convert it (preferably in python) to a .js file array that looks more like this:

```
var variable1 = [
[1,2,3],
[3,4,5],
[5,6,7],
];
```

I'm very new to programming, so any guidance would be very helpful! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open your csv file, then read the lines and write them in your js file.

Basically:
-> Open csv file
-> Create js file
-> Write 'var variable1 = [' in your js file
-> Iterate on csv lines
-> Write them in your js file
-> Write '];' in your js file
-> Close the files

In python:

```
myJSFile = open('Path_to_your_js_file', 'w')
myJSFile.write("var variable1 = [\n")

myCSVFile = open('Path_to_your_csv_file', 'r')
for line in myCSVFile .readlines() :
    myJSFile.write("[%s],\n" % line.strip())

myJSFile.write("];")

myJSFile.close()
myCSVFile.close()
```

That should do the work ;)